# How to render subclass component in angular 2?

Tags: angular, templates

I have a main class, Module which is extended by many subclasses such as TextOnlyModule or ImageOnlyModule.

I have a component, Preview, that contains a Module Array.

Here's a little diagram :

[image]

I'd like, in preview template, to render each Module with its subclass template. In the following example, modules is an Array of Module, and i'd like something to render each module with its template without calling directly each selector as I don't know the Module subtype.

```
<div *NgFor="#module in modules">
    {{module}}
</div>
```

Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could do that programmatically within the `Preview` component using the [`DynamicComponentLoader`](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) class:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <div #someContainer></div>
  `
})
export class Preview {
  constructor(dcl:DynamicComponentLoader,eltRef:ElementRef) {
    this.modules = ...

    this.modules.forEach((module) => {
      dcl.loadIntoLocation(module, eltRef, 'someContainer');
    });
  }
}
```

Here is some plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/UtVpvnTHPiR675lztOcQ?p=preview.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I'm currently using angular 2.0.0-beta.0 and as far as I can see, there's no loadIntoLocation method on renderer.
It seems that setElementProperty is the closest one.

I'm trying to use it like this:
    this.modules.forEach((module) =>{
        renderer.setElementProperty(eltRef,"elements",module);
    }) with my template :
     <div *ngFor="#elements"></div>
but it seems that it's not working at all

Comment: Oh you're right. I made a mistake: it's the `Renderer` class but the `DynamicComponentLoader` one... I updated my answer ;-) Sorry!

Comment: Thank you again for your help Thierry.   I encounter another difficulty. Is this possible to `loadIntoLocation` with an instancied object instead of its `Type` ? I wasn't able to find it in the api doc

Comment: I don't think so... How would you instantiate your component?